# Builtin Octopus deploy repository

Tags: nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy

We're using Teamcity CI for build and Octopus Deploy for deployment.

We want to use Builtin Octopus deploy repository for storing Artifacts instead of teamcity repo. What are the differeneces between them?
Can you help me evaluate the built in Octopus repository. Pro/Cons, any complications you might be facing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One of the key differences is that TeamCity can be used as an externally accessible NuGet server, but Octopus Deploy can't expose any packages it knows about. If you're building components in TeamCity that are exposed as NuGet packages and reused within applications then Octopus Deploy won't be able to handle that scenario.

If you're just building applications and exposing them for Octopus Deploy then my advice would be to push them to Octopus Deploy to manage, otherwise you end up duplicating on disk space as there'll be a copy of the package in TeamCity and a copy of the package in Octopus Deploy once it has downloaded it from the TeamCity NuGet feed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition, the UI and folder structure in OD are much nicer to administer. So if your packages are only ever going to be consumed by deployments then OD is a better option. I've also had issues in TC where the publish step completes, but when OD tries to deploy the package isn't available from the TC repo. I suspect this is an indexing issue internal to TC. Pushing the packages to OD resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The inbuilt Octopus Deploy repository allows you to automatically create and deploy a release as soon as it is packaged and published (usually during a server build). This is great if you want to schedule nightly builds so that your development/test/integration environment is always update to date.

> External package repositories cannot be used to automatically create
>   releases, only the built-in package repository is supported.

[image]

It also maintains packages through a [retention](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Retention+Policies) policy so you don't have to worry about running out of disk space.

[image]

We use two NuGet repositories. One for application packages deployed through Octopus Deploy, and one for shared packaged reusable components using [NuGet.Server](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/hosting-packages/nuget.server).